# how to redirect the users once user has logged in and to get photo ,name and other detaills of the user

Tags: reactjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to do login in react with facebook and we are using this code 
https://gist.github.com/ronit-mukherjee/3e933509643a4ab4e80452bb05c1a073.
However ,my concern is as how to redirect users to some page once the user has logged in sucessfully .As I understand it has to be whitelisted too but the thing is how to redirect .Another thing is that we need these data too 
accessToken as well in response .

Answer (score 0):

Try using this library `react-facebook-login` your code will be much cleaner. And here what you should do after the successful login, just send that data to your API and use `this.props.history.push('/');` to navigate to another page:

```
    onFbAuth = response => {
        let data = {
            id: response.userID,
            email: response.email,
            firstName: response.first_name,
            lastName: response.last_name,
            picture: response.picture.data['url'],
            social: "facebook"
        }

        //data is the object that facebook api sends you back.
        authService.login(data).then((response) => {
           this.props.history.push('/');
        })
    }

    failed = () => {
        console.log('something failed');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <FacebookLogin
                appId='YOUR_APP_ID'
                autoLoad={false}
                fields="first_name, last_name, email, picture"
                onFailure={this.failed}
                callback={this.onFbAuth}
            />
        );
    }
```

Comment: this is the worst module i have come across for login .It sends request to facebook and facebook sends back 302 instead of json .

Comment: @dfsdigging check their documentation and make sure you set up everything good. I'm using it on a couple of projects and it works perfect in all of them.

Comment: @dfsdigging thats the code. Just make sure you are using `YOUR_APP_ID` correctly, and you configured your app on facebook. Or try to `console.log()` response in `failed()` and check what its saying

Comment: @ We don't get any response and at times we do get .Puzzled with this thing of facebook.

Comment: @dfsdigging you should check that out, cause i dont really know. Since my apps are working all perfect with that code